# Powershell script to print out each value in the system path

Tags: windows, scripting, powershell

I found that I can use `$env:Path` within PowerShell to see my current system path. However, everything runs together on one line. Is there a way to pipe the output of `$env:Path` to another command that will print each path value separately (i.e. printing on a new line for everything that is delimited by a semi-colon)?

Currently it prints something like this:

```
C:\Some Test Directory\With\Some\Files\In\It;C:\Some Test Directory\With\Some\Files\In\It;C:\Some Test Directory\With\Some\Files\In\It;C:\Some Test Directory\With\Some\Files\In\It;C:\Some Test Directory\With\Some\Files\In\It;
```

I'd rather have something like this:

```
C:\Some Test Directory\With\Some\Files\In\It
C:\Some Test Directory\With\Some\Files\In\It
C:\Some Test Directory\With\Some\Files\In\It
C:\Some Test Directory\With\Some\Files\In\It
C:\Some Test Directory\With\Some\Files\In\It
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$env:Path.split(";")

PS C:\Users\user> $env:Path.split(";")
C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2011.2.0.1\lib\extralibs\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2011.2.0.1\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
C:\Windows\system32
...
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix you can do this with simply

```
echo $path | tr ";" "\n"
```

You can emulate this workflow on Windows with either of the following:

EITHER

Install [gnu coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) and add the bin directory to your system path

OR

1. Add a folder for your command line tools to your system path. E.g, "C:\Program Files (x86)\bin\"
2. Download tr as part of the [powertools ported from unix](http://freecode.com/projects/ppt). Extract them somewhere else. (E.g, "C:\Program Files (x86)\bin\perl\"
3. Add a bat file called tr.bat with these contents to your bin folder:

> @echo off
>
> perl "C:\Program Files (x86)\bin\perl\tr" %*

(Path should match where you extracted the perl tools)

---

Result

```
C:\>echo %path% | tr ";" "\n"
C:\Program Files (x86)\bin\
C:\Perl\site\bin
C:\Perl\bin
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Python27
...
```

Comment: While this will work, this is WAY overkill for something that you can already easily do from within PowerShell.

Comment: Perhaps, but I offer this to those (like myself) who are from a unix environment and have no interest/motivation to learn powershell.

Comment: Sorry; that sounds a bit condescending. What I mean is I can now pipe that through "grep Windows" and get all the Windows sub dirs in my Path. I have no idea how to do this in Powershell.